# Meaning of 名前が名前だし, 受けでも狙え and ツッコミ

Tags: meaning, interpretation

> 名前は南空ナオミ。元FBI捜査官だそうです。**名前が名前だし**両親が日本にいるのだから日本人なのでしょう。

南空ナオミ is the name of a Japanese detective in death note. I think the author is saying that because of her name and both her parents being in Japan, it appears that she's Japanese (I think し can be used as a "because")

それが無理ならせめて「ワターシ、ニッポンゴシャベレマセーン」と日本語そのままで喋って**視聴者とリュークの受けでも狙え。狙ってどうするというツッコミは聞こえません。**

The author is complaining that the detective Ray Penbar should have done something to revert the situation he was in  to not get killed by kira. Then he says that if that's not possible for Ray to do, he could've make it look like he doesn't speak Japanese (because he is American) and the rest I can't understand. Why is he including the audience and Ryuk, and what does ツッコミ mean?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/%e7%aa%81%e3%81%a3%e8%be%bc%e3%82%80%e6%89%80-is-this-what-it-means/17871#17871

Comment: Also, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13102/slang-for-funny-%e3%81%86%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c/13112#13112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from [this usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60465/5010), `X + が/も + X + だから/なので/etc` is a way to remind X as a reason for something. It roughly means "(as you know,) because of the (unusual) X". Examples:

- 時間も時間なので、今日は帰りましょう。
- 値段が値段ですし、たくさんは売れないと思います。
- 私は性格が性格なもので、よく人と言い争いになることがあります。

---

Your second question is harder to explain, but it's basically a kind of joke called セルフツッコミ, a *tsukkomi* made against one's own *boke*. If you don't know *boke* and *tsukkomi*, please learn them first elsewhere, for example [this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BokeAndTsukkomiRoutine) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17870/5010).

So, in this paragraph, this blog author has been making fun of how useless Pembar was (Pembar could do almot nothing before he was killed). Then he made a *boke* sentence, "Penbar at least should have made Ryuk and the audience laugh by saying 'Watashi nippongo shaberemaseen'!" This may not seem funny to you (it's actually not particularly funny to me, either), but this is intended to be a silly statement, or a *boke*. Here, ワタシニホンゴワカリマセーン itself is recognized as a classic and cheesy Japanese *boke* said to get a laugh (google it if you're interested).

Then 狙ってどうする followed, which roughly means "What's the point of trying to do so (i.e., trying to make them laugh)?", and it's working as a self-*tsukkomi*, the act of correcting his own silly joke and getting another laugh. ～というツッコミは聞こえません ("I don't (want to) hear such a *tsukkomi* like ～") is a bit redundant, but basically he is pretending he said the previous sentence seriously. (Maybe it's like "no *boke* intended, just like how English speakers say "no pun intended" when a pun is intended.)