# Understanding NがNだからって

Tags: grammar

> 『ーーじゃあ、早速いきましょうか士道。**相手が相手だからって**、あまり気負いすぎないこと。確かに彼女の力は強大だけれど、それは今に始まった話じゃないでしょう？いつも通りのデートができればきっと大丈夫よ』

The 相手 and 彼女 refer to the same person. Could you please explain the usage of the construction 相手が相手だからって? Or more generally NがNだからって?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/64503/5010

Answer (score 5):

As you might have figured, N が N だからって, or N が N だからといって, literally means “just because N is N”, or a little more idiomatically “just because N is what it is.”

Your example might be translated as “just because your opponent (or date?) is as strong as she is.” What adjective comes in the place of “strong” depends on the context. It describes how N is expected to be without being explicitly stated.